# MVC5/Routing in ASP.NET 5 (vNext)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

I have a project that we're looking to launch with MVC 5 and ASP.NET 5/dnx46.  I understand that MVC6 has some changes, but the project will likely be launched prior to MVC6 being out of beta - thus ASP.NET5/MVC5.

The problem I'm having is with routing.

Anything MVC5-based is relying on System.Web, which doesn't appear to play nicely with the rest of the project.

So how does one go about setting up a generic MVC-style route?

I've found some resources that include a *ton* of boilerplate code, but I can't imagine that MS is requiring everything be written/overridden just to get some basic routing done outside of MVC6?

Comment: you cannot use mvc5 with asp.net 5. if you need to ship an mvc5 app before mvc6/asp.net 5 is ready you should not try to use any parts of asp.net 5.

Comment: [ASP.NET MVC Boilerplate](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6cf50a48-fc1e-4eaf-9e82-0b2a6705ca7d) may help you find out how to translate your code quicker. It has more out of the box than the standard project template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 5 runs only on ASP.NET 4.x.

ASP.NET MVC 6 runs only on ASP.NET 5 (using DNX).

The MVC versions cannot be mixed between the versions of ASP.NET.

ASP.NET MVC 5 and ASP.NET MVC 6 are however still very similar, though they certainly also have some significant changes.

For example, though the routing *functionality* is largely very similar between MVC 5 and MVC 6, the place where you register the routes is different. Check out the [Music Store](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/master/src/MusicStore) sample app for [how to register routes](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L214-L229) in an ASP.NET MVC 6 app.

Answer (score 0):

The following is added to your Startup.cs to get MVC running.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureRouting(
        routeOptions =>
        {
            // All generated URL's should append a trailing slash.
            routeOptions.AppendTrailingSlash = true;

            // All generated URL's should be lower-case.
            routeOptions.LowercaseUrls = true;
        });

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    application.UseMvc();
}
```

Attribute routing is added by default, so you can use the `[Route]` and/or `[HttpGet]`/`[HttpPost]` attributes instead.

```
[Route("[controller]")] // [controller] is replaced by 'car'.
public class CarController : Controller
{
    [Route("hello")] // Or use [HttpGet]
    public string World()
    {
        return "World";
    }
}
```

The old school routing requires a bit more work. You have to add the routes in Startup.cs

```
application.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "route1",
            template: "hello",
            defaults: new { controller = "Car", action = "World" });
    });
```